# How do I locate the RD Connection Broker Service?

Tags: windows-server-2008, rds

Okay, this might seem strange, but how do I find out where my RD Connection Broker is located?

We have taken over a new domain where the RD connection broker is being used to load balance between 3 RD Session Hosts. This is with Server 2008.

How can I see which server is the connection broker? I can't find it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into the RDS Host Configuration console and look at the RD Connection Broker settings.

Comment: Hmm, it's 2008 so its "Terminal Services" in stead. Is it the same there?

Comment: I don't have a 2008 TS server handy but I believe it's under TS Session Broker settings under TS Configuration.